# Java: Adding ActionListeners to graphical objects

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I got a whole bunch of buttons, is there a way of adding actionListeners to all of them without going `button.addActionListeners(this)` for all of them? it makes the code looks so messy.

Comment: This is precisely what collections and `for` loops are for.

Comment: `it makes the code looks so messy.` sorry really ???, don't extend class or implements whatever

Answer (score 3):

If you want common behavior to all your buttons you need to make them extends an abstract class where you defined the common code. So define your own abstract `MyButtonClass` with its own add listener method.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. But if all the buttons share the same action listener (which is quite strange), maybe they should be stored in an array or collection. You could then do:

```
for (JButton button : allButtons) {
    button.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If all the buttons are on a single container you could register a single `ActionListener` like this:

```
for (Component c: container.getComponents()) {
   if (c instanceof JButton) {
      ((JButton)c).addActionListener(this);
   }
}
```